# Android Relative Layout not working properly on Galaxy S3

Tags: android, amazon-s3, android-relativelayout, galaxy

im working on a design and testing it on:

- Galaxy Nexus 3
- Samsung Galaxy S3

It seems like the S3 doesn't behave so well with some relative layout commands such as:

- Layout_toStartOf
- Layout_toEndOf

Simplified problem down below:

### Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/button1"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### Images

1. In editor and on Nexus 3
2. On Samsung S3

[image: Working properly in Editor and Nexus 3]

[image: Not working proplerly on Samsung S3]

Since im working a lot with scaling and pictures relating to each other, this function is very importaint.

I'd appreciate if someone could share their experiences with me.

Thanks

edit: typos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all there is no resource such as  `android:layout_toEndOf="@id/button1"` .

there are only 2 resources for relative layout to arrange according to any widget by its id `toLeftOf` and `toRightOf` check your code.

**Edit:**

`toEndOf` and `toStartOf` is added recently in API level 17 i.e. android 4.2 versions so it will not be found in lower versions of android

Comment: are you talking about the "toEndOf" or the button1? I thought I only need to reference a resource, once I added it ( @+id/ )

Comment: I am talking about toEndOf there is no such resource. check my edited answer

Comment: I found it here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_toEndOf

Comment: ok just use different resource like toLeftOF/toRightOf and see if it makes any difference. I think toEndOf/toStartOf is not supported by every versions of android because in my xml file its showing error no resource found

Comment: thank you very much! i'd like to upvote your answer but i'm missing reputation ;)

Comment: It is not correct to say there is no such resource as android:layout_toEndOf, as has been clearly shown by the posted link.

Comment: @coernel no problem. If need any more help you know where to find me

Answer (score 0):

Have had the same problem:

I used the ToStartOf and toEndOf to align a graphic of fixed size to a 1px wide graphic that was scaled.

[Graphic 1] <-- [Graphic 2 (1px scaled to 20dp)] <-- [Graphic 3]

They wont align correctly when you build it from the right to the left. When you say toLeftOf a scaled graphic it will the new graphic left of the original size of the picture and not at the end of the scaled picture - Thus overlap.

[Grap[hic 1 Gra]phic 2][Graphic 3]

A workarround coud be to build the graphic from Left to the right, put all the elements in a relative layout as a Module and align the different modules to each other.

Thx for the info with the API level with the ToStartOf and ToEndOf functions!